what factors would affect the change in the concentration of the hydrogen in the plateau region for the metal hydrides?
I was trying to understand that in the plateau region of the PCT curve , we use the Van't hoff Equation, even if we considered the sloping factor we will have the following equation:
$\ln(\frac{P}{P_o}) = \frac{\Delta H}{RT}+\frac{-\Delta S}{R}+f_s(C-C_m)$.
This equation was considered from the following research paper:
link:https://doi.org/10.1016/0360-3199(94)90097-3
here for the sake of mathematical calculations, if we considered that sloping factor is zero, the equation transforms to:
$\ln(\frac{P}{P_o}) = \frac{\Delta H}{RT}+\frac{-\Delta S}{R}$.
By logic, why we see the concentration increases during the plateau region even at constant pressure and temperature.
Can anyone explain what will cause the change in the concentration in the PCT curve when considering the Van't Hoff Equation at constant pressure and temperature, assuming we are going with an ideal PCT curve with a straight horizontal line in PCT curve.
